# .htaccess tweak needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^books$ /my/directory/pro/books [NC,L]
```

It works fine as long as the user does not add a trailing slash, e.g.

```
mysite.com/books   // works
mysite.com/books/  // doesn't work
```

How can it be modified to work with or without the trailing slash?

Comment: Note that mysite.com/books// is a valid url for the same resource.

Comment: Hmm... I keep getting 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^books/?$ /my/directory/pro/books [NC,L]
```